# How to reset the form values without showing validation error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Form - HTML**

Email Address:
                
                    
                
                Email address field is required  
                Too Long    
                Invalid email address 
            
            
                Password:
                
                    
                
                Password field is required 
            
            
                Login

**Login Controller - Angular JS**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('loginController', loginController);

    loginController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService'];
    function loginController(ApiService, $location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.userLogin = userLogin;
        (function initController() {
            // reset login status
            AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
        })();

        function userLogin() {
        FlashService.clearNotification();
            ApiService.userLogin(vm.user).then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    FlashService.Success(response.message); 
                    } else {
                    FlashService.Error(response.message);
                }
                vm.user.$setPristine();
            });
        }
    }   
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set `vm.user = {};` and `vm.user.$setPristine(true);` too.

```
loginController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService'];
function loginController(ApiService, $location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.userLogin = userLogin;
    (function initController() {
        // reset login status
        AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    })();

    function userLogin() {
    FlashService.clearNotification();
        ApiService.userLogin(vm.user).then(function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                FlashService.Success(response.message); 
                } else {
                FlashService.Error(response.message);
            }
            vm.user = {};
            vm.user.$setPristine(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Umakanta Behera!

Now form fields are clearing but still its displaying required field validations.

Comment: Is your form name attribute is "user" ? I mean <form name="user"></form>.

Comment: Nope this is my form <form name="form" role="form" ng-submit="vm.userLogin(form.$valid)" novalidate>

Comment: You should change to <form name="user" role="form" ng-submit="vm.userLogin(form.$valid)" novalidate> or vm.form.$setPristine(true);